# Generically typing an argument while passing it a default value

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to write a `nest()` function which accepts 2 object entities and a key, and nest the second in the first in the provided key.

entity 1

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

entity 2

```json
{
  "few": "baz"
}
```

entity 2 nested in entity 1 in `wow`

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "wow": {
    "few": "baz"
  }
}
```

I came with the following implementation, which works like a charm

```
type Nested <
  LeftEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  RightEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  NestKey extends string
> = LeftEntity & {
  [Key in NestKey]: RightEntity
}

const nest = <
  LeftEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  RightEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  NestKey extends string
> (
  leftEntity: LeftEntity,
  rightEntity: RightEntity,
  nestKey: NestKey
): Nested<LeftEntity, RightEntity, NestKey> => {
  const nested = {
    ...leftEntity,
    [nestKey]: rightEntity
  } as Nested<LeftEntity, RightEntity, NestKey>

  return nested
}
```

Now I'd like to give `nestKey` a default value, and make it an optional parameter. Thus I naively tried :

```
const nest = <
  LeftEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  RightEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  NestKey extends string
> (
  leftEntity: LeftEntity,
  rightEntity: RightEntity,
  nestKey: NestKey = 'meta' // <= HERE
): Nested<LeftEntity, RightEntity, NestKey> => {
  // ...
}
```

But compiler complains :

> TS2322: Impossible to assign type 'string' to type 'NestKey'.
> 'string' can ben assigned to type constraint 'NestKey', but 'NestKey' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.

While I perfectly understand why this complains (I do, that's not my question); I'm wondering what would be the pattern to accomplish what I want.

I'd add some constraints to the solution :

- Avoid use of typecasting if possible
- Having a perfect typing of the return type (make it autocomplete with vscode, specifically)

Is that possible ?

Comment: Consider [the following workaround](https://tsplay.dev/WvGxYw) using default generic parameters.

Comment: @caTS the trouble is that implementation leads to unsafe behavior when explicitly passing the generic type. See [the trouble](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6xbw) (scroll it)

Comment: I don't know if it's possible like this, but you could definitely [use overloads](https://tsplay.dev/WzPxeN).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement it, the generic type can be omitted, and the nestKey too, if the generic param is omitted or provided as "meta"

[Playgorund link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMoB4CwAoKUAyEAZsAKIB2wAlqFBAB5JnLxQBKEAxgPYBOyaiHpTIBzADRQArmQDWZLgHcyAPjHZcrSiIAWpCtRC0GEJi3bc%20A4ENETpcxSrU5YCYAGkIh%20o2ZRBwiLYylAAvPhEelQ0AGRQAN7qUADanobCrohpALoAXGxauuTRINgAvtjY3GSIUGRuYehJBMTFBka%20Zpy8-AG2UrLySqpJmjpR7T4mfuY9VjbiAw7DzrhwWV4d0yx9Io0ARAC2EMAAhvtQAPSXUMhEp5IANsBQx2fBUAAUSY%20RbaD5FoTUCrKBCcb-ED5MZFfQgpL1DZQzIeTbhI4nc5QU4sdaowzXO6EB7PV6Y7AASnyeJQaCBkIkMOBIAkeLSIVCIUSLmqtURSFQ4W5uFwADpxb9WnCWUlcMl%20Tl8uDYSUkmVsbi3LT6dLGYVmay3OzKi4eCdJDwyHUtchyibeS9To1%20ZgXPFtF58rsyqD3VwvdZAhUsMpvm6PciAOSELhcSM%20pJ%20-KRgBGpx48cpJuuUAA6rwZPAqlwalxfqLHlwRJ9TqK3qcKQBue0l2op51uNDxU4BhY%20hIp3tBiT7DiSRBcQ4ABR4XDA%201D3dy%203O-fig6g%20xT%2037o-HwEnM7n%20yb2cuXBk2BTorHE%20ns7Azaw2Gu3EOYEep2ERaw1-rUBNE0gA)

```js
const nest = <
  LeftEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  RightEntity extends Record<string, unknown>,
  NestKey extends string = "meta" // default meta
> (
  leftEntity: LeftEntity,
  rightEntity: RightEntity,
  nestKey: NestKey = "meta" as NestKey //default meta
): Nested<LeftEntity, RightEntity, NestKey> => {
  const nested = {
    ...leftEntity,
    [nestKey]: rightEntity
  } as Nested<LeftEntity, RightEntity, NestKey>

  return nested
}
```

if you try like this, it will complain

```js
const a = nest<
  {hey: string},
  {ho: string}
>(
  {hey: 'foo'},
  {ho: 'bar'},
  "aaa"
)
```

Comment: Hey; I also came with this, experimenting. Through the fact `NestKey` can't be inferred is a bit annoying :/

Comment: I couldn't find a workaround for that, but nevertheless, types are checked correct, and you have VS code auto-complete support